# how to start time group on a specific date pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that I have grouped by datetime '12M'. I would like it to be grouped by 12M ending Dec. 31. Currently it is yearly grouping ending Jan. 31. It seems that there must be a simple way of doing this but I have been unable to find anything documenting one I am asking for. I've tried setting TimeGrouper('12M') but it won't start the counting from the beginning of the year, but rather is uses the first date index as a starting point

```
dfy = dfy.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('12M'), 'fec_id', 'trans_typ', 'cmte_id'])['amount'].sum()
dfy.head()
#dfy.to_csv('out.csv')

date        fec_id     trans_typ  cmte_id  
2007-01-31  C00002600  24K        C00000729    1000
                                  C00002840    1000
                                  C00004325    1000
                                  C00005157    1000
                                  C00009985    1000
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) with `freq=A`:

[Offset aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

```
g = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='date', freq='A'), 'cand_id', 'trans_typ'])['amount'].sum()
print g

date        cand_id    trans_typ
2001-12-31  H2HI02110  24K              2500
2007-12-31  H8IL21021  24K             -1000
            S6TN00216  24K              2000
2008-12-31  H2PA11098  24K              1000
            H4KS03105  24K             49664
            H6KS01146  24K              2000
            H6KS03183  24K              1000
            H8KS02090  24K              1000
            S6TN00216  24K              2500
2009-12-31  H0MO00019  24K               500
            H8MO09153  24K               500
            S0MO00183  24K              1000
            S0NY00410  24K                 0
            S2KY00012  24K              2000
            S6OH00163  24K             -4000
            S6TN00216  24K             -2000
            S6WY00068  24K             -3500
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `closed='left'` argument with `pd.TimeGrouper`.

```
pd.TimeGrouper('12M', closed='left')
```