# pandas: pd.grouper trouble grouping by end of year date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following data frame:

```
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/108michael/ms_thesis/master/pacs.can.cl.abbridged'

df=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/108michael/ms_thesis/master/pacs.can.cl.abbridged')

df= df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date']), inplace=False)

df.head(3)

    cycle   pacid   cid     amount  date    catcode     type    di  feccandid   amtsum
date                                        
2010-10-13  2010    C00000901   N00031317   1000    2010-10-13  B2000   24K     D   H0FL19080   3000
2009-03-23  2010    C00082917   N00027464   5000    2009-03-23  B1000   24K     D   H6IA01098   3500
2009-05-13  2010    C00034405   N00024875   1000    2009-05-13  A5200   24K     D   H2IL08088   2000
```

Below I perform a group-by:

```
 df['amtsum'] = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='date', freq='A'), 'catcode',\
    'type', 'pacid', 'di', 'feccandid']).amount.transform('sum')

    cycle   pacid   cid     amount  date    catcode     type    di  feccandid   amtsum
date                                        
2010-10-13  2010    C00000901   N00031317   1000    2010-10-13  B2000   24K     D   H0FL19080   3000
2009-03-23  2010    C00082917   N00027464   5000    2009-03-23  B1000   24K     D   H6IA01098   3500
2009-05-13  2010    C00034405   N00024875   1000    2009-05-13  A5200   24K     D   H2IL08088   2000

​
```

I would like for the `date index` to end on the end of the year, e.g. `2010-12-31`. I had this problem [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059477/how-to-start-time-group-on-a-specific-date-pandas/36060065#36060065) and I got a working solution. Unfortunately, now that I am revisiting this part  of my code the solution is no longer working. I have also tried the following:

```
df['amtsum'] = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('12M', closed='left'), 'catcode',\
'type', 'pacid', 'di', 'feccandid']).amount.transform('sum')

df.head(3)
    cycle   pacid   cid     amount  date    catcode     type    di  feccandid   amtsum
date                                        
2010-10-13  2010    C00000901   N00031317   1000    2010-10-13  B2000   24K     D   H0FL19080   1000
2009-03-23  2010    C00082917   N00027464   5000    2009-03-23  B1000   24K     D   H6IA01098   3500
2009-05-13  2010    C00034405   N00024875   1000    2009-05-13  A5200   24K     D   H2IL08088   1000

​
```

but the results are still not what I am looking for.
Does anyone have a clue on this?

Comment: Please show code and the erroneous results

Comment: @EdChum: I've updated the question to reflect the code I'm using and the output.

Comment: Why does http://stackoverflow.com/a/36059999/5247609 this answer not work?

Comment: @Chris: Thank you for your comment. I have tried the  `TimeGrouper` as well and the results are the same.

Comment: Have you set the label parameter? label : interval boundary to use for labeling; left or right, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html

Comment: @Chris: Thank you for your suggestion. I just tried applying the kwarg `label`as you suggested. I tried `start` `end` `left` `right`as exemplified in the link you provided. All gave the same result

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

index= pd.date_range(start=dt.date(2014,02,04), periods=200, freq='1M')
data = np.random.random(200)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=["col1"])

group = pd.TimeGrouper('A')

grouped = df.groupby(group)

for key, g in grouped:
    print key

example = grouped.mean()
print example.head(3)
```

gives:

```
>>
2014-12-31 00:00:00
2015-12-31 00:00:00
2016-12-31 00:00:00
2017-12-31 00:00:00
2018-12-31 00:00:00
2019-12-31 00:00:00
....

                col1
2014-12-31  0.602693
2015-12-31  0.427651
2016-12-31  0.630363
```

You can always iterate over the groups and aggregate the results manually.However, on closer inspection it seems you are using '12M' with time grouper, whereas you want 'A'.

Comment: I tried applying your solution to my df. Namely, I created a variable `group = pd.TimeGrouper('A')` and used it in my `group-by` my results did not mirror yours. Unfortunately I think it has something to do with the df. I'm going to try to find a work-around. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: What is your pandas version, I use 0.18. If all else fails, just use for the: `for key, group in grouped:` idiom, and perform the aggregation yourself (e.g. add result and key to lists, concat after the loop). This will give you dataframes which only fall within a calendar year, you can use complex aggregation to your hearts content.

Comment: @ Chris: I just learned that my version is 17.0. I'm going to try an update and see what happens. Thanks again, I never would have guessed that it my Pandas version is off, since I use ipython and just assumed that all was up to date.